# Python program that: Generates a random number between 1 and 100

Tags: python

I have tried everything i can still doesn't work. Please any help would be appreciated.
Please i have been able to allow it generate one hint, but i need it to generate 3 different hints the 3 different times the user presses 0 for the hint.
I have it give the hint even OR odd. i need it to give extra 2 hints.
**Part 1:**

- Generates a random number between 1 and 100.
- Allows the user 10 tries to guess what the number is.
- Validates the user input (if user-input >100 or user-input<0) then this is invalid input and should not cost the user to lose any tries.
- Gives feedback for each time the user makes a guess. The feedback tells the user whether the number entered is bigger, smaller, or equal to the number generated (and exits the program).
- Tells the user if they lost after he/she consumes all the 10 tries. Gives the user 10 tries to guess the number. If the user exhausts the 10 ties. The user loses.

**Part 2:**

- After 2 unsuccessful tries, the program should start offering hints for the users (by having the user input the number 0).
- Each hint should be generated within a function of its own.
- Each hint will cost the user two tries (the program should indicate this to the user)
- The user is allowed a max of 3 hints only.
- The program should randomly pick which hint it is going to use and display to the user.
  **(example of a hint is : 1-    The number is bigger than or equal the square of some X (X is an integer and is the largest integer square that is less than the user input))**

Here is my program so far:

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('WELCOME! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Hello, ' + myName + ', I generated a number between 1 and 100.')

unsuccessful_tries = 0
hint_taken = 0
while guessesTaken < 10:
    if unsuccessful_tries > 1 and hint_taken<3:
        print('Press 0 to get hint')
        need_hint = int(input())
        if need_hint == 0:
            hint_taken += 1
            guessesTaken += 1
        if number%2==0:     
            print('The Generated number is an EVEN number')
        else:
           print('The Generated number is an ODD number')


    print('Take a guess.\t%d Attempts Left'%(10 - guessesTaken))
    #10-guessTaken gives the number of tries left
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    #validating the user's input
    if guess >100 or guess<0:
        continue

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break
    unsuccessful_tries+=1

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: "I'm stuck at part 2" - With what?

Comment: i cant really do nything on the part 2. i cant figure a way forward. please help me if you can

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. If you are trying to get the community to do your homework, that's poor form. However, if you make your question more specific and tag it with self-learning, you may get a better response.

Comment: im trying to incorporate the part 2 into my program to have a better interactive number guess program sir, so if you can help me in anyway i would appreciate it

Comment: You didn't validate the user's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me nudge you towards solving part two:

1. You're already keeping track of the user guesses with the `guessesTaken` variable
2. A random 'Hint' can be simply randomly choosing through a list of pre-made hints ( if you had 5 pre-made hints, you could just choose a random number between 1-5, and select that one)
3. 'Costing' the user two tries is as evaluating whether they have enough guesses to afford it ( i.e: if they are at guess number 9, they can't afford to give up 2 guesses), and then add two to the guessNumber if they accept a hint.
4. You can evaluate the amount of hints taken with a counting variable, though given your parameters (they have to have two unsuccessful guesses to receive a hint, with a maximum of 3 hints total), they would not be able to have 3 hints.

This is the most exact answer i can give you, since you haven't provided any code for part 2 that isn't working or that you need help with.

**loose example for point #2: choose a random function from a list:**

```
my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create variables which keep tracks of the number of unsuccessful tries and hint taken. If the number of unsuccessful tries is greater than 2 and hint taken is less than 3 then you should ask the user if he wants hint.

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Hello, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

unsuccessful_tries = 0
hint_taken = 0
while guessesTaken < 10:
    if unsuccessful_tries > 1 and hint_taken<3:
        print('Press 0 to get hint')
        need_hint = int(input())
        if need_hint == 0:
            hint_taken += 1
            guessesTaken += 1
            print('Here is hint')
            #Do this by yourself chose a hint and display

    print('Take a guess.\t%d Attempts Left'%(10 - guessesTaken))
    #10-guessTaken gives the number of tries left
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    #validating the user's input
    if guess >100 or guess<0:
        continue

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break
    unsuccessful_tries+=1

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: i updated my code, kindly review and see if you can help me

Comment: I can see only one hint where are the other hints?

Comment: i)The number is smaller than or equal the square of some K (K is an integer and is the smallest integer square that is larger than the user input)
ii) The number is a multiple of some Y (Y is an integer)
iii)   The number is even or odd.. these are the 3 hint i intend to include, but i only know how to include the one i have already done